# How to speed up mysql query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, performance, php, query-performance

I have query :

```
SELECT
    `school`.`ARCO_name`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_7`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_8`,
    `degree_o`.`degree_code`,
    `accredit`.`full_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`total_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`pc_terminal`,
    `accredit`.`stud_fac_ratio`
FROM school
    INNER JOIN `student-` ON `school`.`scid`   = `student-`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `degree_o` ON `student-`.`scid` = `degree_o`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `accredit` ON `degree_o`.`scid` = `accredit`.`scid`
    ORDER BY `school`.`ARCO_name` ASC LIMIT 0, 25
;
```

It's working and everything but it need about 20 seconds to execute.
Is something wrong in my query?
What can I do to speed up process?

Comment: You really need to give us some more information: Which indexes do you have, how big are you tables, etc.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE `student-`; SHOW CREATE TABLE `degree_o`; SHOW CREATE TABLE `accredit`;

Comment: I dont see any where conditions in this sql, so I assume the result set will be common for all. So why not use a view and update the view when the data changes or schedule a task so it changes updates the vie wevery day ?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on all the foreign keys.  In this case, all of the fields named scid and then also on on school.ARCO_name.  Post the explain plan for this query.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT
    `school`.`ARCO_name`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_7`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_8`,
    `degree_o`.`degree_code`,
    `accredit`.`full_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`total_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`pc_terminal`,
    `accredit`.`stud_fac_ratio`
FROM school
    INNER JOIN `student-` ON `school`.`scid`   = `student-`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `degree_o` ON `student-`.`scid` = `degree_o`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `accredit` ON `degree_o`.`scid` = `accredit`.`scid`
    ORDER BY `school`.`ARCO_name` ASC LIMIT 0, 25
;
```

Two Suggestions

1. Perform `LIMIT 0, 25` on school table before the INNER JOINs
2. INNER JOIN `school.scid` to the other three(3) tables

Here is my propsed query

```
SELECT
    `school`.`ARCO_name`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_7`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_8`,
    `degree_o`.`degree_code`,
    `accredit`.`full_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`total_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`pc_terminal`,
    `accredit`.`stud_fac_ratio`
FROM
    (SELECT scid,ARCO_name FROM school ORDER BY ARCO_name LIMIT 0,25) school
    INNER JOIN `student-` ON `school`.`scid` = `student-`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `degree_o` ON `school`.`scid` = `degree_o`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `accredit` ON `school`.`scid` = `accredit`.`scid`
;
```

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-06-25 12:13 EDT**

To speed up the subquery, make sure you have this index:

```
ALTER TABLE school ADD INDEX ARCO_name_scid_ndx (ARCO_name,scid);
```

### **UPDATE 2012-06-25 12:18 EDT**

AS pointed out by @yercube in his comments to my answer, you may want to attach the student-id from to degree_o and degree_id over to accedit. Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT
    `school`.`ARCO_name`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_7`,
    `student-`.`ClassSize_8`,
    `degree_o`.`degree_code`,
    `accredit`.`full_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`total_faculty_3`,
    `accredit`.`pc_terminal`,
    `accredit`.`stud_fac_ratio`
FROM
    (SELECT scid,ARCO_name FROM school ORDER BY ARCO_name LIMIT 0,25) school
    INNER JOIN `student-` ON `school`.`scid` = `student-`.`scid`
    INNER JOIN `degree_o` ON `student-`.`studend_id` = `degree_o`.`studend_id`
    INNER JOIN `accredit` ON `degree_o`.`degree_id` = `accredit`.`degree_id`
;
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original query. Unless every school has only one student (and other assumptions are true).

Comment: It may give less or more rows in the result set. Or different ones.

Comment: @ypercube Based on the original query, if `school.scid`=`student-`.`scid`, `student-`.`scid`=`degree_o.scid`, and `degree_o.scid`=`accredit.scid`, then `school`.`scid` has to be equal to `degree_o`.`scid` and `accredit`.`scid`. If Wolfe87 had used `student_id` to go from `student-` to the last two tables, then this redefines the query. In fact, the semantics would be different. I see your point in that a school has students, students have degrees, and degrees have accreditations. Since scid (which is school) was used throughout the original query, I rewrote the original query accordingly.

Comment: Even if `scid` is the Primary Key in all 4 tables, the 2 queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @ypercube, you're right. They are not equivalent. The EXPLAIN plans should be differ greatly. Personally, I expect the EXPLAIN plan for my answer to look worse but perform better. I have seen this happen many times. I even tested this when I answered a question on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757) when I forced a LIMIT clause to execute earlier.

Comment: I'm not talking about the execution plan but the result-set. Anyway, the OP can clarify things if he bothers to add the tables' definitions. No need for us to argue over split water.